# Clojurescript templating from html files

Tags: clojurescript

I'm new to clojure / clojurescript so there may be a simple solution to this I am overlooking, but here is my problem:

I have existing html files (just raw html, no variables or anything) I'd like to use as partials for a clojurescript project (These html files are things like navigation, footer, etc). I'd like to require these html templates in the clojurescript project, and then have the templates be inlined in the compiled js so I don't have to do any ajax calls for templates in production or copying over the html files to be available to the client in production. Projects like requirejs and browserify have plugins to let you just 'require' the html files - is there an equivalent for clojurescript?

I know of libraries to do templating / dom manipulation so that is not an issue. It is simply the translating of multiple external html files into inlined strings/dom nodes/whatever to be included in the production js.

Thanks

Comment: take a look at https://github.com/ckirkendall/enfocus may fit what you needs. clojurescript, compiled templates.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if this might work for us. Not sure if it solves the problem of having a single js file _including_ the templates, but seems solid for the rest - I'll have to try it out and see. Appreciate it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do this using macros executed at compile time.

**project.clj**

```
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2202"]]
  :source-paths ["src"]
  :cljsbuild
  {:builds
   [{:id "main"
     :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
     :compiler
     {
      :output-to "resources/main.js"
      :optimizations :whitespace
      :pretty-print true}}]})
```

**src/cljstemplates/core.clj**

```
(ns cljstemplates.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :refer (resource)]))

(defmacro deftmpl
  "Read template from file in resources/"
  [symbol-name html-name]
  (let [content (slurp (resource html-name))]
    `(def ~symbol-name
       ~content)))
```

**src/cljs/web.cljs**

```
(ns cljstemplates.web
  (:require-macros [cljstemplates.core :refer [deftmpl]]))

(deftmpl head "header.html")
(deftmpl nav "nav.html")
(deftmpl foot "footer.html")
```

This will generate vars `head`, `nav`, `foot` containing strings read from files in resources/ folder.

**resources/nav.html**

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Tweets</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Output (main.js):**

```
cljstemplates.web.nav = "\x3cnav\x3e\n  \x3cul\x3e\n    \x3cli\x3eTweets\x3c/li\x3e\n  \x3c/ul\x3e\n\x3c/nav\x3e\n";
```

Comment: Woah, this is awesome thanks. Being a clojure newbie I'll have to read this a few times before I get it but this is super helpful.